# Can we build mobile app using JavaScript (NOT Java)?

Tags: web-development, android

I'm confused I use to build mobile app couple of years ago and I know that android is java I read some framework like Ionic HTML/JavaScript Framework that can export to mobile app. I going to have android projects soon and I will going back to java for mobile app, I'm at web development. I saw this that Ionic framework and its not Java I'm very curious with this because I love javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, Ionic bundle your javascript code into JAVA and creates a binary APK and it can also do the same for IOS. you have React Native as well, PhoneGap, Cordova, and many other frameworks that do the same. also, there's an entire tech stack nowadays that's called PWA which is a progressive web application that can be downloaded as a windows application, mobile application and used on the web either online or offline.

[React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)

Comment: Wow that was powerful

Comment: Make sure you are familiar with the drawbacks of this sort of SDKs. They are not as powerful as we think and are not exempt from limitations and constraints (in comparison with native SDKs)

Comment: that's something the React Native solved for example as it allows direct access to Native SDK whether its IOS or Android. and if the answer helped you then be my guest and mark it the answer. thank you.